# Proof of absolute convergence series if and only if the series formed from its positive terms and its negative terms both converge - Proof Question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

The following claim was made in *Spivak's Calculus 2nd ed - pg.473*:

> A series is absolute convergence if and only if the series formed from its positive terms and the series formed from its negative terms both converge.

The following is the proof of the claim:

[image]

The overall flavor of the proof I understand, but there are two steps which have me befuddled.

1. How is $|a_{n}| = [a_{n}^{+} - (a_{n}^{-})]$?
2. How $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}^{+} = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|a_{n}| \bigg)$ ?

If I could understand how these are derived I would be good. What simple things am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Earlier in the book, either in a comment in the text or in a theorem or lemma or exercise, he "must" have pointed out this:

> > If $t\in\Bbb R$ then $t=t^+-t^-$ and  $|t|=t^++t^-$.

(For the proof, consider the cases $t>0$, $t=0$ and $t<0$.)

**Edit.** Here I'm assuming that for example $(-1)^-=1$, as is right and proper. Evidently in the book in question $(-1)^-=-1$, so these formulas will look different.

Comment: I was thinking that was the case with regards to him pointing this out and i vaguely remember it possibly being the case, but I went over the absolute value section of the book and didn't find the concept

Comment: @dc3rd Don't have the book here, but again I have a very good guess: Look in the section where he introduces $t^+$ and $t^-$. ("positive part" in the index...)

Comment: Found the question in the exercises and of course it would be one of the few I have not attempted.... let me work on it and should I have issue I'll ask for help in the comments

Comment: So I've successfully done the proof in the book and from that I could deduce that $t =\ max(t,0) + \min(t,0) = t^{+} + t^{-}$. It is in the next steps I'm having trouble working it out. I tried to show $t = t^{+} - t^{-}$, but I haven't been able to arrive at the result. For the $|t|$ version, I think I have the result, but it is the negative case I need verification: assuming $t < 0$: |t| = $\frac{-(t) + |t|}{2} + \frac{(-(t) - |t|}{2}$. Now since $t < 0$, multiplying these terms by $-$ will turn those terms to positives and then $\max(t,0) + \min(t,0)$ would be satisfied.

Comment: @dc3rd Don't know if it matters, but no, $\min(t,0)\ne t^-$. OR maybe his notation is simply different - the exercise seems to say $t=t^++t^-$, while in my notation that's $|t|$.

Comment: Yes in the exercise he notates it as $t = t^{+} + t^{-}$ where the first is deemed the "positive" part and the second the 'negative". So where does the second subtraction come from in the proof of the series?

Comment: @dc3rd Show that $|t|=t^+-t^-$. (Again this is clear in each of the cases $t>0$, $t=0$ and $t<0$.

Comment: I'm still not arriving at the same expression you stress I should be getting. Showing the $t < 0$ case: $\frac{|t| + 0 + ||t| - 0|}{2} + \frac{|t| + 0 - ||t| - 0|}{2} = -\bigg(\frac{-(t) + |t|}{2} + \frac{-(t) - |t|}{2} \bigg) = \frac{t + |t|}{2} + \frac{t - |t|}{2} = t^{+} + t^{-}$. So where am I going wrong if I'm supposed to be getting $|t| = t^{+} - t^{-}$? The same thing happens in the $t>0$ case.

Comment: @dc3rd I can't say exactly where you're going wrong because I don't quite follow what you're doing. This is trivial. "**Case 3:** $t<0$. Now $t^+=0$, $t^-=t$ and $|t|=-t$, so $t^++t^-=0+t=t$ and $|t|=0-t^-=t^+-t^-$."

Comment: I'm using the definition of $\max(|t|,0)$ and $\min(|t|,0)$ explicitly. So by definition: $|t| = \max(|t|,0) + \min(|t|,0)$. Now the definition of $\max(|t|,0) = \frac{|t| + 0 + ||t| - 0|}{2}$ and $\min(|t|,0) = \frac{|t| + 0 - ||t| - 0|}{2}$. And from here, the comment above is what I had worked out, using the definitions stated here and since treating the $t<0$ case that is where the extra minus sign comes from.....I think I am not treating the second set of absolute value bars correctly.

Comment: @dc3rd What you call the definition can't be the _definition_ of $|t|$, because there's a $|t|$ on the right side. The definition is just $|t|=t$ if $t\ge0$, $|t|=-t$ if $t<0$.

Answer (score 0):

A series converges absolutely iff its tail sums $\sum_{n\ge N} |a_n| \to 0$ as $N \to\infty$.  What does that say about the sums of the positive and negative parts of the terms?

Comment: I'm going to "say" that $\sum_{n \geq N}a_{n}^{+}$ and $\sum_{n \geq N}a_{n}^{-}$ both go to zero, but I don't understand why or the reasoning behind it....

Comment: uh, $|x^+|, |x^-| \le |x|$.